# Quaternion isn't normal!

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, quaternions

I use the following scheme:

```
Quaternion: [ w, x, y, z ]
```

Then I use Euler Angles and convert it to a quaternion, as following:

```
bank = 180; // x axis
heading = 80; // y axix
attitude = 20; // z axix

DegreeToRadian = 3.14/180;

c1 = cos(heading/2*DegreeToRadian);
c2 = cos(attitude/2*DegreeToRadian);
c3 = cos(bank/2*DegreeToRadian);

s1 = sin(heading/2*DegreeToRadian);
s2 = sin(attitude/2*DegreeToRadian);
s3 = sin(bank/2*DegreeToRadian);

q.w = c1*c2*c3 - s1*s2*s3;
q.x = s1*s2*c3 + c1*c2*s3;
q.y = s1*c2*c3 + c1*s2*s3;
q.z = c1*s2*c3 - s1*c2*s3;
```

And then I normalize:

```
n = sqrt(q.w*q.w+q.x*q.x+q.y*q.y+q.z*q.z)
q = {w/n, x/n, y/n, z/n}
```

$w+x+y+z$ should equal $1$, but it is wrong!
And when I convert the quaternion to a matrix, I have a big distortion.

I created this in Excel,
you can see it online.
[OneDrive Excel](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FF0EE7F9FA35B452!418&authkey=!AEfRxg1qlBYRL4U&ithint=file,.xlsx)
[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nD0FRLNMbUy1ccXkctAJPIbXJpVXoB8wsk_VqCBdGkk/edit?usp=sharing)

Please, Help me.

Comment: *Quaternion isn't normal!* - I know, but hey, what is ?

Comment: $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$ should equal $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normalized with respect to the sum of the squares; why would you expect that the sum of the components would equal 1 then?  Looking at your google doc, the sum of the squares is 1, the way it should be.

Why is this the case?  Consider a very simple quaternion, representing a rotation about $\hat x$ by an angle $\theta$.

$$q = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + i \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$

It's not true that $\cos \frac{\theta}{2} + \sin \frac{\theta}{2} = 1$, but it is true that $q q^* = \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = 1$.